# Does HttpSendRequest automatically retry if the connection is reset?

Tags: wininet

I'm running a 64 bit Windows app written in C++ on a Windows 10 desktop. Using `HttpSendRequest` to make a call to one of our services. I know that with a particular call, the server is dropping the connection do to an issue, but it appears that HttpSendRequest then makes and additional call automatically, and then just returns after the second call.

Details:

Make a PUT request to http://myserver/myservice/request_params

This creates a parameter set on the server, and returns a GUID

Make a GET request to http://myserver/myservice/report/aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd

Where aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd is a GUID, that is supposed to be a one use request id.

The service is having an issue performing the intial GET request, and drops the connection. I know this is happening because when I run Wireshark, I can see two calls to the GET endpoint being made. The first time, a TCP RST comes back and the connection is closed.

I've stepped through our code and verified that we are making one call to HttpSendRequest, but this is returning true, with a 404 status, and the error message that the server would make on a second call to the GET endpoint. It appears that WinINET sees the connection drop, and automatically tries again.

On the client side, we would rather that HttpSendRequest return false on the first call.

Any thoughts on how to turn off this behavior or detect it when `HttpSendRequest` returns?

Comment: You might try playing with the `WINHTTP_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES` option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/option-flags

Comment: @Luke -  I don't think WINHTTP_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES should effect this, as it's clearly sending the request, so it does connect, it's just that the connection gets dropped. Documentation states that this is for number of connection retries, not request retries, but MS documentation isn't always accurate.